# Displaying Javascript Array in pre-coded HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I need to display a list of 100+ football player numbers, names, weight, age, and heights. I would rather not copy/paste the same exact div I have set up and change them manually. I was wondering if there is a way to display each set of data in the html layout I already coded? The only thing I can find on google is Javascript generating it's own table. Here is an example:

Here's the array:

```
var playerArray = [
    ["#25","Player1", "Weight1", "Height1", "Age1", "Position1"],
    ["#99","Player2", "Weight2", "Height2", "Age2", "Position2"],
    ["#77","Player3", "Weight3", "Height3", "Age3", "Position3"],
    ["#63","Player4", "Weight4", "Height4", "Age4", "Position4"],
    ["#43","Player5", "Weight5", "Height5", "Age5", "Position5"],
    ];
```

and here is my html where I want the data displayed:

```
<div class="rosterlist">
            <div class="p_name">[[NUMBER]] <span class="light_text2">/ [[NAME]]</span></div>
            <div class="roster_line_2"><div class="p_pos">[[POSITION]]</div><div class="p_height">[[HEIGHT]]</div><div class="p_grade">[[AGE]]</div><div class="p_weight">[[WEIGHT]]</div></div>
        </div>
```

If it's not possible, just let me know and I'll get to my copying and pasting:(

Comment: This is easy to do also without a library.

Answer (score 2):

This is best solved through data binding and templating.
I recommend using a template based framework like KnockoutJS.
This will give you the ability to specify a single entry that gets repeated for each entry

Link: http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: Awesome, never heard of that before. Looks like it should do it!

Answer (score 2):

As Stano states, this is straight-forward to do without a library:

```
var i, k, html = '', line = '';
var template = ''+
  '<div class="rosterlist">' + 
    '<div class="p_name">[[0]] <span class="light_text2">/ [[1]]</span></div>'+
    '<div class="roster_line_2">'+
      '<div class="p_pos">[[5]]</div>'+
      '<div class="p_height">[[3]]</div>'+
      '<div class="p_grade">[[4]]</div>'+
      '<div class="p_weight">[[2]]</div>'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>'+
'';
var data = [
  ["#25","Player1", "Weight1", "Height1", "Age1", "Position1"],
  ["#99","Player2", "Weight2", "Height2", "Age2", "Position2"],
  ["#77","Player3", "Weight3", "Height3", "Age3", "Position3"],
  ["#63","Player4", "Weight4", "Height4", "Age4", "Position4"],
  ["#43","Player5", "Weight5", "Height5", "Age5", "Position5"],
];

for( i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
  line = template;
  for( k=0; k<data[i].length; k++ ) {
    line = line.replace('[['+k+']]', data[i][k]);
  }
  html += line;
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
```

And in your markup:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally a fan of Handlebars

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/BZ2nZ/

the HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="rosterlistTemplate">
<div class="rosterlist">
    {{#each this}}
    <div class="p_name">{{number}} <span class="light_text2">/ {{name}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="roster_line_2">
        <div class="p_pos">{{position}}</div>
        <div class="p_height">{{height}}</div>
        <div class="p_grade">{{age}}</div>
        <div class="p_weight">{{weight}}</div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

The data:

```
var playerArray = [
    ["#25","Player1", "Weight1", "Height1", "Age1", "Position1"],
    ["#99","Player2", "Weight2", "Height2", "Age2", "Position2"],
    ["#77","Player3", "Weight3", "Height3", "Age3", "Position3"],
    ["#63","Player4", "Weight4", "Height4", "Age4", "Position4"],
    ["#43","Player5", "Weight5", "Height5", "Age5", "Position5"],
    ];
```

Convert the data:

```
var data = _(playerArray).map(function(playerInfo){
    return _.object(['number','name','weight', 'height', 'age', 'position'], playerInfo);
});
```

Putting the template to use :

```
var template = Handlebars.compile($('#rosterlistTemplate').html());
$('#container').html(template(data));
```

I'm using underscore to convert the format of the data you have into something like this

```
[
    {number: xx, name: xx, weight: xx, height: xx, age: xx, position: xx},
    {number: xx, name: xx, weight: xx, height: xx, age: xx, position: xx},
    {number: xx, name: xx, weight: xx, height: xx, age: xx, position: xx},
]
```

If you can get the json in that format then you don't need underscore and can skip the 'convert data' step altogether.

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j88fV/)**

#### JavaScript

```
<script>
    var playerArray = [
        ["#25","Player1", "Weight1", "Height1", "Age1", "Position1"],
        ["#99","Player2", "Weight2", "Height2", "Age2", "Position2"],
        ["#77","Player3", "Weight3", "Height3", "Age3", "Position3"],
        ["#63","Player4", "Weight4", "Height4", "Age4", "Position4"],
        ["#43","Player5", "Weight5", "Height5", "Age5", "Position5"],
    ];

    window.onload = function () {
        var template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
        var list = document.getElementById('list');

        for (var i = 0, l = playerArray.length; i < l; i++) {
            var values = {
                'NUMBER': playerArray[i][0],
                'NAME': playerArray[i][1],
                'WEIGHT': playerArray[i][2],
                'HEIGHT': playerArray[i][3],
                'AGE': playerArray[i][4],
                'POSITION': playerArray[i][5],
            };

            var t = template;
            for (var p in values) {
                t = t.replace('[[' + p + ']]', values[p]);
            }

            list.innerHTML += t;
        }

    };
</script>
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="list"></div>

<script id="template" type="text/html">
    <div class="rosterlist">
        <div class="p_name">[[NUMBER]] <span class="light_text2">/ [[NAME]]</span></div>
        <div class="roster_line_2"><div class="p_pos">[[POSITION]]</div><div class="p_height">[[HEIGHT]]</div><div class="p_grade">[[AGE]]</div><div class="p_weight">[[WEIGHT]]</div></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the array like this:

```
var str = '';
var len = playerArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    str += '<div class="p_name">' + playerArray[i][0] +
        '/ <span class="light_text2">' + playerArray[i][1] + '</span> \
</div> \
<div class="roster_line_2"> \
    <div class="p_pos">' + playerArray[i][5] + '</div> \
    <div class="p_height">' + playerArray[i][3] + '</div> \
    <div class="p_grade">' + playerArray[i][4] + '</div> \
    <div class="p_weight">' + playerArray[i][2] + '</div> \
</div>';
}
document.getElementById('rosterlist').innerHTML = str;
```

Full javascript code here: http://jsfiddle.net/VuKmv/ (compatible also with IE6+)

Comment: Wait, you've actually started up IE6 to test this? And I thought I was anal-retentive because I still keep a IE7 around.

Comment: Tested it in [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), Mr Listy Rimmsy.